# MergeFS/UnionFS on Windows 10 (or WSL Debian)?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am looking for a way to merge multiple file/folder paths under a single path, on Windows.

The goal is to have access to various files/folders scattered over multiple paths (of various length) under a single path.
The ultimate goal is to provide this single path to a backup software so that it backups my various files/folders in a single action.

The simple approach would be to create a folder with bunch of symlinks.
But some backup software treats symlinks as such ("pointers to a location"): they do not dereference the link (and don't access the targeted content).

Say I have the following drive content:

```
C:\
├── Program Files\
│  (…)
│   └── Apache\
│       └── DocumentRoot\
├── Users\
│   ├── User1\
│   │  (…)
│   │   ├── AppData\
│   │   │  (…)
│   │   │   ├── .ssh\
│   │   │   └── .gitconfig
│   │   ├── Coding\
│   │   ├── Documents\
│   │   └── Images\
│   └── User2\
│      (…)
│       ├── Documents\
│       └── Images\
└── Windows\
   (…)
    └── System32\
        └── drivers\
            └── etc\
                └── hosts
```

I want a *merged file system* containing only (filtering out anything not explicitly specified) the following folders/files:

- `C:\Users\User1\Coding\`
- `C:\Users\User1\AppData\.gitconfig`
- `C:\Users\User2\Documents\`
- `C:\Program Files\Apache\DocumentRoot\`
- `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Something like:

```
X:\
├── Program Files\
│   └── Apache\
│       └── DocumentRoot\
├── Users\
│   ├── User1\
│   │   ├── AppData\
│   │   │   └── .gitconfig
│   │   └── Coding\
│   └── User2\
│       └── Documents\
└── Windows\
    └── System32\
        └── drivers\
            └── etc\
                └── hosts
```

*(It could also be under an existing drive letter, e.g. `C:\MergedFs\`)*

I am not very aware of what [Windows File System Proxy (WinFSP)](https://winfsp.dev) can do (directly or via a third-party softwares that relies on WinFSP) but is there a solution?

Of course a read-only *merged file system* is totally fine: as it's only for backup, no need to write anything (I guess).

Comment: Symlinks or junctions would be my initial way to go about this.  The "backup software" can be something as simple as a zip file run by a script under the scenario you describe.  I know that isn't what you want to do but that is what I myself would do.